# ReactJS | Objects are not valid as react children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, error-handling, formik

I am using React with Formik in order to create an manage a form. `(Error Handling, submission etc)`. I am having a little bit of trouble with handling errors from the server.

To solve it, I used Formik's builtin `<ErrorMessage />`. So, in the first element of the form I added it. Like the one below:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="pb-2">
            <label className="font-weight-bold" htmlFor="username">
              Username <Asterisk />
            </label>
            <Field
              validate={this.debounceUsernameValidation}
              className={classNames('form-control', {
                'is-invalid': errors.username && touched.username
              })}
              placeholder="Username (Required)"
              autoComplete="false"
              name="username"
              type="text"
            />
            {errors.username && touched.username ? (
              <div className="text-danger">{errors.username}</div>
            ) : null}
          </div>
          <ErrorMessage name={errors.username} component="div" className="text-danger small" />
</form>
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I am not sure what I did wrong. Could you help me sovle this, and make me understand what this error is about. I mean the errors that come either from the server or client side, should be an object.

And when React says `If you need to be an object, use an array instead`. I really don't get it. Thanks for your time.

Error object. This is generated by Yup, which works in conjactions with Formik:

```
{ "username": "Username is Required", "password": "Password is required", "confirmPassword": "Password Confirmation is Required", "group": "Group is required" }
```

Comment: What does `errors.username` contain? If it was an object that would cause this problem.

Comment: Well, the errors is an object with strings, containing the client side errors. Check the updated description for the error object. You can see the username is a string. And it comes as a string from the server as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `<ErrorMessage ... />` wrong. The name prop should be a string with the same value as the key that your error object has. Something like this:

```
<ErrorMessage component="div" name="username" />
// --> {touched.username && error.username ? <div>{error. username}</div> : null}
```

---

If we follow the documentation:

> **`name`**
>
> `name: string` **Required**
>
> A field's name in Formik state. To access nested objects or arrays, name >can also accept lodash-like dot path like `social.facebook` or >`friends[0].firstName`

Take a look to the example in the DOC:

https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/errormessage